# Struts Json Plugin Date conversion when date field is empty

Tags: json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I have issues with Json plugin not able to convert my empty string to a null date object. In spring mvc I have initbinder in my controller which takes care of this. How can I achieve this with struts json plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code on JS front to set my json response to null for date fields if it is empty which took care of my problem

Thanks